# EXM custom token accessing mail's context language

Tags: exm

I was able to create a custom token according https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/create-a-custom-persnalization-token.html without any issues in `Sitecore 9.1.1` instance. I needed to create one token for a formal salutation and one for informal salutation which provides the greeting text considering gender of the contact and if `firstname/lastname` are given.

So my question is are we able to access the mail's context language within the custom token?

Because I need some text from a settings item to be added to the token according the language of the mail and depending on the gender of the contact like shown on below screenshot,

[image]

I know I could fetch the translation according the preferred Language of the contact, but that could lead to a mixture of languages in the mail if the mail language is different to the preferred Language of the contact. So consideration of the mail's language would be the best option.

I tried to access it within the custom token like `ExmContext.Message.TargetLanguage` but message is always null.